# Is it possible to fetch data from an api with cloud funtions of Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm thinking about mobile app project that takes data (News) from an api provider into Firebase real-time database so that later when users search for 
News they get it from my Firebase database .
The question is that , can I do this work just by using cloud functions ?
If not ,could you please provide an alternative and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloud Functions execute arbitrary Node.js code, so they can certainly fetch data from an API and put it in the Realtime Database. Note that your Firebase project must be on a paid plan to be able to make external (non-Google-service) network calls.

One issue you might run into based on your description: Cloud Functions run as a response to an event such as a database write or an HTTPS request. You will need some way to trigger the function code to ingest data from an API. If you want to ingest data on a regular basis, you might want to take a look at the [firebase-cron](https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron) sample that walks you through using App Engine cron together with Cloud Functions.

Comment: thanks a lot . your answer is very satisfying.